# How to get Service (server files) for PHP from a Proto spec?

Tags: php, protocol-buffers, grpc

Despite the fact that PHP servers aren't officially supported, shouldn't I get a Service from protoc+grpc_php_plugin anyways?
Running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
protoc --proto_path=./ \
       --php_out=./generated \
       --grpc_out=./generated \
       --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=../../../../grpc/bins/opt/grpc_php_plugin \
       ./greeter.proto
```

Over:

```
syntax = "proto3";

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I'm getting only the `GreeterClient.php`.
Shouldn't I get a `GreeterService.php` as well?